# Letter box in iPhone5

Tags: xcode4.5, iphone-5

It works like magic to get rid of the letter box in iPhone5. Just put in the picture
Default-568h@2x.png.
And the app will open with the NavBar in the top in iPhone5 instead of in a letter box.

But how to reverse that?? If I remove the Default-568h@2x.png it still opens unboxed.

Is it possible to go back to the previous letter boxed version?

Or in a new project using Xcode 4.5 to build for letter boxed apps?

Comment: Looks like it is cached somewhere. Did you try Cleaning the project, and uninstalling it from the device/simulator?

Comment: Yes you are right. Did not help to uninstall the app but when I also trashed the DerivedData folder and rebuilt, it worked and I am back to the letter box. Could be the the same for a new project which has the Default-568h@2x.png already there. Remove and rebuild? Have not tried that yet

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get back to the letterbox (3.5-inch display) on the iPhone 5 seems to be

1. Remove the 4-inch display sized launch image from the project.
2. Delete the app from the phone.
3. Clean the project using Product > Clean.
4. Install the app to the phone.

I asked [how can this be done without deleting the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806888/how-can-i-re-enable-the-letterbox-mode-using-the-iphone-5-and-xcode-4-5-2-withou), but it doesn't seem to be possible.