# How can I re-enable the letterbox mode using the iPhone 5 and Xcode 4.5.2 without deleting the app?

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, iphone-5

I'd like to re-enable the letterbox mode on the iPhone 5 for my app. Using Xcode 4.5.2 and building an app for iPhone 5, I generated an 1136x640 launch image and it was named Default-568h@2x.png. I have sinced removed the launch screen and in the project summary the space for that image is empty. Also, I have removed any instances I found within the project folder. However, my app continues to be displayed using the full screen on the iPhone 5 and what I want is to be able to use the letterbox mode again. I believe this can be accomplished by deleting the app, but how can I re-enable the letterbox mode using the iPhone 5 and Xcode 4.5.2 without deleting the app from the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap 'Product'->'Clean' in Xcode and remove the application from your phone. Then rebuild your project and there shouldn't be any cached version of the Default-568h@2x.png anywhere.

Comment: Just have read your edit. I'm not sure if it is possible without deleting the app.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because the written answer is the closest to answering the question. Imran was also helpful in narrowing down the problem. For now, there doesn't seem to be a way to get back to the letterbox mode without deleting the app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting the app from the device and redeploying it? I have had issues with icon files etc not being refreshed unless the app is removed and freshly deployed.

Alternatively you can connect your iPhone and open organiser. Select the device and app and hit 'Download'.

Then add the archive you just saved back to your project. Then go to the Project Scheme Drop Down Edit Schemes>Run and select the app data package.

Redeploy your app from scratch and it will contain the saved state.

Comment: I just edited the question to indicate that I don't want to redeploy the app.

Comment: When you connect your iPhone and look at your apps in organiser there is an option to 'Download' which will download documents and data. You can download the data, delete and redeploy your app then upload/restore its data files.

Comment: Not sure if it will also restore any cache that might have been causing the problem though ;) but its worth a try if you want to keep your data.

Comment: Thanks, Imran. That works to get back to the letterbox and keep the data but is a bit more than what I want to do to toggle the letterbox.

Comment: Why do you want to toggle it? Maybe we are approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: My reasons are for testing the appearance for previous phones, and for generating screenshots for previous phones, using only the iPhone 5. It is important for me to use a phone and not the simulator.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but that doesn't provide the answer to my question as I still need to delete the app and clean the project. I'm editing data on the phone so it's more important to preserve the phone's data rather than loading it from an archive.

Comment: i'm not sure what you want to do is achievable, not sure if its a bug that the icons and splash screens don't update without deleting though. If you need to test both screen sizes why don't you just develop against one and then schedule in some testing for the additional screen size. That would be a much more efficient way of working instead of testing with both every single time you make a change.

Comment: Also ui will be the last thing on your list after core app features so should usually be done at the end of development.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I disconnected my iPhone, removed the App from the iPhone's installed Apps, did a Project Clean in XCode, reconnected the iPhone and did a full build and redeploy to the iPhone.

Success! Letterboxing!