# iOS App for 3.5" Screen Size

Tags: ios, retina-display, autolayout, iphone-5

I'm making a new app for iPhone, and since all the graphics works are done for 3.5" support I don't want to change it for new 4" screens. The problem is when I'm running it in 4" simulator it automatically stretches the content to match the 4" size. I was wondering how can I force it to center the app vertically like old apps on iPhone 5?

I also configured my xibs and views:

```
Size = Retina 3.5"
Deployment = iOS 5.0
Use Autolayout = Unchecked
```

Comment: Can you put screen shot

Comment: Sorry I can't. But just imagine a 3.5" sized app stretched for 4" screen, like what autoresize does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By deleting default-568h@2x.png (reference and file) from project. and also deleting the app from simulator and doing a "clean" and then "build" it will work. But there will be a warning for deleted image.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the newest version of Xcode.
Every new app created has automatically a default-568h@2x.png which enables the widescreen device support. You can't disable it.

But it is possible to create a new project with an older version of Xcode (around 4.4) which doesn't make this image so there won't be an widescreen device for this target.

Comment: Will it make any problem in app submission and review?

Comment: Not yet, but the all mighty Apple can change the requirements any time.

Comment: By deleting default-568h@2x.png (reference and file) and also deleting the app from simulator and clean and then build it again, It's working. but there is a warning showing for deleted image and I'm not sure if they will approve it in submission!

Comment: Afaik, you can't turn it of my removing the image. If it's really working, i'm wrong.

Comment: But it is definitely possible to submit it to the appstore.

Comment: I did it, it's possible :D . But since there will be a warning in my app I don't know if it's going to be rejected or not.

Comment: This is similar to what I worked through in Xcode 4.5 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598191/letter-box-in-iphone5/14046781). I don't think it will cause an App Store rejection. It just means it won't be optimized for the iPhone 5.

Comment: @yinkou It might appear to fail because both Xcode's build and incremental upgrade processes do not *remove* resources which are no longer being built; the easiest way around this is to do a clean build/install.