# Display App in 3.5" Resolution on iPhone 5 for Development/Debugging

Tags: testing, user-interface, resolution, iphone-5

Does anyone know if there is a way to force an app you're developing to run in a 3.5" screen size mode if you're on an iPhone 5, just for dev/debug purposes? Something such as what might look like a toggle in the Development section of Settings or something. In other words, run the app such that it LOOKS like it's running on a non-5 iPhone (black bars on top/bottom), that way I can test certain UI functions.

For clarification, I'm NOT saying "I don't want to support iPhone 5" - I most certainly do. Also, I'm aware that I can do the 'old' retina display in the simulator, but I do not want to use the iOS Simulator as the app includes libraries that do not support i386 architecture, uses push notifications, and heavily relies on GPS to function correctly. I'm just looking for a way to test both aspect ratios on the same device to save money/time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that by removing the app from device, deleting the Default-568h@2x.png launch image, cleaning the project, and re-running app, I can get the functionality I'm looking for, although not as nicely as a toggle switch.

[Letter box in iPhone5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598191/letter-box-in-iphone5)